# Change of Variables:Why are the new variables set perpendicular to each other?

Tags: multiple-integral

If I use the change of variables for evaluating an integral ${\int\int}_R$ then when I use transformation why is a right-angle co-ordinate system for the new variables.

For example, to evaluate an integral the following transformation is used $u=y-x$ and $v=4y-x$ now $y-x$ and $4y-x$ are graphs not at right angles to each other which would imply $u$ and $v$ and are not perpendicular but despite this, we set $u$ and $v$ perpendicular to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed, this coordinate transformation is not merely a rotation and scale change, but also a *skewing of the angle* between the axis.  A square in the new coordinates was translated from a parallelogram shape in the old system.

The change of area is included in the Jacobian factor.

$$\begin{align}\iint f(x,y)\,\mathrm d\langle x,y\rangle &= \iint \begin{Vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial\langle (v-4u)/3,(v-u)/3\rangle}{\partial\langle u,v\rangle}\end{Vmatrix} f((v-4u)/3,(v-u)/3)\,\mathrm d\langle u,v\rangle\\[1ex]&= \iint \begin{Vmatrix}-4/3 & 1/3\\-1/3&1/3\end{Vmatrix} f((v-4u)/3,(v-u)/3)\,\mathrm d\langle u,v\rangle\\[1ex]&= \iint \tfrac 13 f((v-4u)/3,(v-u)/3)\,\mathrm d\langle u,v\rangle\end{align}$$

---

This still happens to be a linear transformation (the Jacobian factor is a scalar).  Other transformations have curves in the old coordinate system become the new axis.

Comment: So you mean that the Jacobian should take care of the inconsistency that might arise due to skewing of the angle??

Comment: No, it takes care of the transformation's affect on the area.

Comment: So I should ignore the distortion of the angle and not account it anywhere in the solution?